# Create a new function or just normal print to get value from another function

Tags: python, function

I have this function which contains the `self.w(weights)`
I wish to make another function or any normal way to take the weight from the function above and then print it.

```
Class tech:
def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.t = 0
        self.y = y
        self.w = np.zeros(shape=(len(y),x)) 

def update(self,y,f):
        #print(list(zip(labels,self.w)))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            #print (y[i])
            #print f
            l = max([0,1-y[i]*np.dot(self.w[i],f)])
            #print(range(len(self.w[i])))
            eta = self.know(l,f)
            self.w[i] += eta * y[i] * f
        self.t += 1
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function, or just directly print the variable.

Assuming you make an object from the class tech called tech_obj:

```
tech_obj = tech()
print(tech_obj.w)
```

or you could make a function:

```
def weight(self):
    print(self.w)
```

Comment: Thank you sir but I have a problem, I do not want to print from the init but from the def update (function) within the class. Is it possible?

Comment: @Jackson Yes, you would just include the code print(tech_object.w) inside of the update function.

Comment: I am sorry for misleading but I would like to create another function that is not within the tech Class to retrieve the weights value from the tech Class and this function should be able to print the weight values. This function should take the def update(function) weight values instead of the init weight values. What about this?

Comment: You can use the top code in a function. It works the same way: print(tech_obj.w) if you are outside of the class.

Comment: True and thank you again but the problem is it prints weight values for init def and not from the def update. Def update contains updated weight but init only 0 for all

Comment: Okay, now I understand your problem. Can you update the post to include all of your code? First thing to check is if you are running the tech.update() function.

Comment: But my codes are pretty long. So far for my Class it has only these in the post. However, I tried many methods but not sure on how to retrieve the updated values within the def update for weight values. Whenever I print, I kept getting the values from the init def and not update def

Comment: Can you post your code into pastebin and link it? I can't really help if you if I can't see the rest of the code.

Comment: Alright, I will post it. But there is no easy way to get the print(self.w) within the def update? For example, instead of print(tech_object.w) when outside of the class, we can't do something like print(tech_object.update.w)? Some way to get into the update within the class and take the values.

Comment: If the code is working properly, when you use update(), the w variable will update everywhere. So if I run the following code: print(tech.w) then tech.update() then print(tech.w), the output should be 0, and then change to 10 (or whatever number the calculation spits out). This is I why I want to look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your update function does update the class variable `w`, then you should be able to access it via attribute:

```
t = tech()
print(t.w)
```

as @The Tesseract's Shadow said.

Then a more pythonic way to do it is making it a property:

```
# In your class
@property
def get_weight(self):
    return self.w
```

So you can access this variable anywhere by:

```
t = tech()
print(t.get_weight) # Initial weights
t.update(y,f)
print(t.get_weight) # Updated weights
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Class tech:
def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.t = 0
        self.y = y
        self.w = np.zeros(shape=(len(y),x)) 

def update(self,y,f):
        #print(list(zip(labels,self.w)))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            #print (y[i])
            #print f
            l = max([0,1-y[i]*np.dot(self.w[i],f)])
            #print(range(len(self.w[i])))
            eta = self.know(l,f)
            self.w[i] += eta * y[i] * f
        self.t += 1

# x_, f_ and y_ are variables that you must have defined
t = tech(x_,y_)
t.update(y_,f_)
print(t.w)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class tech:

result = ""
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.t = 0
    self.y = y
    self.w = np.zeros(shape=(len(y),x)) 

def update(self,y,f):
    #print(list(zip(labels,self.w)))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        #print (y[i])
        #print f
        l = max([0,1-y[i]*np.dot(self.w[i],f)])
        #print(range(len(self.w[i])))
        eta = self.know(l,f)
        self.w[i] += eta * y[i] * f
    self.t += 1
    global result = self.w[i]

def test():
    print("result")
```